# Specifying variables in master Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am writing a master Ansible playbook which is including playbooks. Now, I want to set variables that all the playbooks specified within it use. How do I specify variables in this playbook?
I know that one of the options is to include vars_files and use it with each of the playbook. Example: - include: abc.yml
                         vars_files: vars.yml

I am using Ansible 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3):

First I would really recommend you to [update](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#what-version-to-pick) your Ansible to latest version. It is very easy to do so, no reason to stay behind.

Having said that, there are many ways on how to specify variables in your master playbook. All these are more or less the same with any other playbook. Briefly mentioning:

a. [Define](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variables-defined-in-a-playbook) them in your playbook itself

```
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    http_port: 80
```

b. [Separating](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation) into a variable file, as you already said:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    favcolor: blue
  vars_files:
    - /vars/external_vars.yml
```

vars/external_vars.yml

```
somevar: somevalue
password: magic
```

Other possibilities include:

c. [Using facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts)

d. [Registering output into variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables)

Additionally, which may be important for your case:

d. You can [pass variables into includes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse):

```
tasks:
  - include: wordpress.yml wp_user=timmy
  - include: wordpress.yml wp_user=alice
  - include: wordpress.yml wp_user=bob
```

e. Passing [variables in command line](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line):

```
ansible-playbook release.yml -k "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"
```

`-k` is shorthand for `--exra-vars`.

There might be other ways too that I may be missing at the moment.